# Strange effect of arabxetex/bidi on figure counter

Tags: captions, bidi, arabxetex

I have a strange bug using XeLaTeX: 
I include `caption.sty` and use a command like `\renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{figure}}` to make an adjustment to the figure counter. If then I include `arabxetex.sty`, the adjustment I made to the counter gets reverted.

See this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{caption}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{figure}}

\usepackage[utf]{arabxetex} 
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Arial}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Test figure}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

And compare:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{caption}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{figure}}

%\usepackage[utf]{arabxetex} 
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Arial}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Test figure}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Does anyone now why this happens? 
I am aware that `arabxetex.sty` is loading `bidi.sty` and that there is the load order: first `caption` then `bidi`. But this order is respected in my case.

BTW: Loading `arabxetex` directly after `caption` would resolve the problem. But I am bound to this specific order of the commands as `arabxetex` is going to be loaded by a style package, while the first 4 lines are in the class. I'm also aware of the possibility to use `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{figure}}}`, which would also work around the problem.

However, I'm really wondering: Is there a bug in `arabxetex` or `bidi` and what else is going to be affected by it? Maybe there's a lot more I need to put into `\AtBeginDocument` ;)

Thx.

Comment: I can't see that it is a bug, you simply have two packages  with commands that are redefining `\thefigure` so naturally which one wins depends on the order you execute the commands.

Comment: Ah, I see. But isn't it a bad style at least to use \renewcommand on an external command in a package? What if you have two packages doing this, which one would you include first? (I know the same goes to my address as I was just writing a package using \renewcommand on \thefigure.)

Comment: sometimes it's bad style but usually that's just the way it is, see all the packages redefining `\cite` you can't really stop them interacting in bad ways. I haven't looked  what arabxetex is doing but probably switching between latin and arabic scripts for the numbers depending on context, hard to say it shouldn't be doing that. you get similar issues with babel languages eg `\figurename` is figure and you could redefine it to say table, but if you load babel and change language it'll get redefined again to a language variant, in the babel case it does provide hooks to add a definition

Answer (score 1):

There is no strange thing; just put

```
\renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{figure}}
```

after loading `arabxetex` package.